# period of recurring decimals

Tags: abstract-algebra, fractions, project-euler

The period of a recurring decimal fraction $1/d$ is equal to the multiplicative order of $10$ mod $d$.

For fractions with even period, the digits sum to 9 i.e.

$1/7 = 0.(142857)...$

$$142\\
857\\
\_\_\_\\
999$$

It seems every prime number has that property. Can somebody please point me to a proof of that ?

Also. what's the relation between the period of $1/mn$ and that of $1/m$ and $1/n$ ?

PS : see problem [26](http://projecteuler.net/problem=26) in projectEuler

Comment: It’s certainly not true that the period of $1/(mn)$ is the same as the period of $1/m$. Did you mean something else?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midy%27s_theorem

Comment: @Lubin corrected that. but for n=2 or 5 it's true

Answer (score 2):

Consider doing the long division of $1$ by $p$ where $p$ is a prime. As you do the division, you will get $p-1$. After this the process repeats with each digit $d$ replaced by $10-d$.

Example:
$$
10/7 = 1, ~\text{Remainder} = 3\\
30/7 = 4, ~\text{Remainder} = 2\\
20/7 = 2, ~\text{Remainder} = 6
$$
Since $6=7-1$ we can stop. We have up to this point the digits 1,4,2. So the remaining digits are 8,5,7, i.e.
$$
1/7 =0.142857 \,142857 \,142857 \,\cdots
$$
Try the same for $1/17$ You will get the digits $05882352$ and remainder 16.
You can verify this from
$$
17 \times 5882352 + 16 = 100000000
$$
Hence
$$
1/17 = 0.05882352|94117647 \,0588235294117647\, 05882352|94117647
$$
where I have drawn a $|$ to show where the second half of the digits come.

More formally,

$$\frac{1}{7} = 0.142 + \left(1-\frac{1}{7}\right)\times 10^{-3}$$

Applying the above equation recursively,

$$\frac{1}{7} = 0.142 + \left(1- \left(0.142 + \left(1-\frac{1}{7}\right)\times 10^{-3}\right)\right)\times 10^{-3}$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{7} = 0.142 + \left(1- 0.142\right)\times 10^{-3} - \left(1-\frac{1}{7}\right)\times 10^{-6}$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{7} = 0.142857\bar{9} - \left(1-\frac{1}{7}\right)\times 10^{-6} = 0.142857 + \frac{1}{7}\times 10^{-6} $$

Comment: @UnadultaratedImation Thanks for expanding on my answer. Nice work, much appreciated

Comment: Can you explain what d stands for